# WebAPI: How to do attribute routing for Post, Put and Delete verbs

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I am new in WebAPI. Somehow I manage to do attribute routing for get type request but do not know how to do it for `Post`, `Put` and `Delete` verbs

Please see my sample code and come with modified code where some one would show me how to do attribute routing for `Post`, `Put` and `Delete` verbs.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    static readonly ICustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();

    [HttpGet, Route("GetAll")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("GetByID/{customerID}")]
    public Customer GetCustomer(string customerID)
    {
        Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return customer;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("GetByCountryName/{country}")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
    {
        return repository.GetAll().Where(
            c => string.Equals(c.Country, country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        customer = repository.Add(customer);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Customer>(HttpStatusCode.Created, customer);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { customerID = customer.CustomerID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }

    public void PutProduct(string customerID, Customer customer)
    {
        customer.CustomerID = customerID;
        if (!repository.Update(customer))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteProduct(string customerID)
    {
        Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        repository.Remove(customerID);
    }
}
```

### Customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Region { get; set; }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not testet but I think it should look like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    static readonly ICustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{customerID}")]
    public Customer GetCustomer(string customerID)
    {
        Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return customer;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/GetByCountryName/{country}")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
    {
        return repository.GetAll().Where(
            c => string.Equals(c.Country, country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        customer = repository.Add(customer);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Customer>(HttpStatusCode.Created, customer);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { customerID = customer.CustomerID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{customerID}")]
    public void PutProduct(string customerID, [FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        customer.CustomerID = customerID;
        if (!repository.Update(customer))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{customerID}")]
    public void DeleteProduct(string customerID)
    {
        Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        repository.Remove(customerID);
    }
}
```

Comment: please include all urls for all action name because i have seen u change my route. say for example my route was `[HttpGet, Route("GetAll")]` u changed it to `[Route("")]` would u please tell me the reason why u change the route or what was wrong in my route ? my route was not friendly for REST compatible ? please answer.

Comment: how to test post action from browser url ? if not possible tell me which tool i should use and specially how to test post action where i need to pass customer or list of customer json. my customer class added. thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to try swagger (nuget package Swashbuckle) which will generate you a site where you see all the endpoints and you can even invoke them from there (and it will add templates for customer etc..). A good tool for invoking web requests is Postman.

Comment: from Swashbuckle can we invoke web api by url like what people do with fiddler ? when we test post method from fiddler then we have to generate json by hand and paste in fiddler for testing.

Comment: No, swashbuckle generates you a web frontend where you can invoke the methods using a few clicks. Just give it a try. Fiddler is a generall solution - way more powerfull and complex whereas swagger just generates you a frontend to test your backend (and you can gernate your clients (proxies) for the most common languages)...